# Filtering a list based on a condition - c#?

Tags: c#, list, linq, lambda, filtering

I have a list of items with the following pattern of results in a variable named dataList

{PH:8,PDate:3/22/2021,
PH:8,PDate:3/23/2021,
PH:4,PDate:3/24/2021,
PH:8,PDate:3/29/2021,
PH:8,PDate:3/30/2021,
PH:4,PDate:3/31/2021,
PH:8,PDate:4/5/2021,
PH:8,PDate:4/6/2021}

The list may have more items like this and I just put a few to understand the pattern. And the list has a type which can hold an <int,DateTime> object.

The week of the day starts on Monday. So from the above list the first 3 items belongs to the same week. Second 3 items belongs to another week and the last 2 items belongs to a different week.

I want to filter this like below

{PH:20,PDate:3/22/2021,
PH:20,PDate:3/29/2021,
PH:16,PDate:4/05/2021}

which is like the sum of PH for each week. Any helps appreciated Thanks.

Comment: it's unclear what you are having trouble with, the question reads like problem statement, do you have some code to do this that you are having trouble with?

Comment: @Keith Nicholas  I don't have any neat code to share for now. You are right its a problem and Need code to solve this.

Comment: I think you want linq's `Where` or `Aggregate` function..

Comment: @Richard Barker - can you help me with some sample code.

Comment: I'd love to, but I'm assuming this is some sort of learning assignment and I know you can figure it out with the information we've given you. `Where` will let you filter but won't do the summing, `Aggregate` will let you do the summing, but you won't end up with a list.  You'll have to combine those I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

given you don't really have any code, you want to do something like the following where we group by week number starting on monday, then select  the first items date and sum all the ints.   Then when printing out we need to adjust the first items date to be the start of the week by subtracting off the first day of week.

```
 var list = new List<(int, DateTime)>();
        list.Add((8, new DateTime(2021,3,22)));
        list.Add((8, new DateTime(2021,3,22)));
        list.Add((4, new DateTime(2021,3,24)));
        var r = list.GroupBy(l =>
                CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Calendar.GetWeekOfYear(l.Item2, CalendarWeekRule.FirstFullWeek,
                    DayOfWeek.Monday))
            .Select(g => (g.Sum(x => x.Item1), g.First().Item2))
            .ToList();
        
        r.ForEach(i => Console.WriteLine($"{i.Item1} {i.Item2 - new TimeSpan(i.Item2.DayOfWeek - DayOfWeek.Monday, 0,0,0)}"));
```

Comment: Thanks @Keith Nicholas this helped to solve my issue.